# C#, Data Type operations

Tags: c#

I'm sorry, a know that it is not sow serious ....

i want to do some operation in C#, How I can do this one ?

```
decimal resultTK = (42 - Convert.ToDecimal(RouteA.Text)) * 21.25 ;
lblResultA.Text = Convert.ToString(resultTK);
```

I have some error in Data Type !

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to implicitly convert between decimal and double. Try:

```
decimal resultTK = (42 - Convert.ToDecimal(RouteA.Text)) * 21.25M;
```

(the M on the constant specifies that it is a decimal)